# Pasar Seleccion de un DataGridView a otro formulario

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando el `CellContentDoubleClick` de mi DataGridView

```
Entradademercancia frm = new Entradademercancia();
        frm.txtrnc.Text = dtgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        frm.btnbuscar.Select();
        this.Hide();
```

el codigo funciona pero solo la parte del `This.Hide();`
es decir el valor que debe de enviar no llega al otro formulario y no me indica ningun error

Comment: @gbianchi el formulario esta abierto. te explico: el usuario esta en un formulario para darle entrada a una mercancia necesita llenar una serie de campos para empezar a hacer la lista de mercancia que va a ingresar pero necesita indicar a que proveedor le va a comprar y debe de realizar una busqueda por RNC y si no sabe el RNC tendra que consultarlo y ahi es donde se abrira el formulario de consulta de proveedores ya dentro de este selecciona del GridView  con un double click y entonces eso debe de llevar la info al formulario que ya estaba abierto por eso no esta el Frm.Show por que esta open

Comment: Si le pongo el frm.show me abrira otro formulario y entonces perdera el avance que haya alcanzado el otro formulario

Comment: Entiendo, @gbianchi pero osea le estoy indicando cual formulario es cual por eso creo la referencia "Formulario receptor" "Nombre para usar la referencia"= new "Formulario receptor" y utilizo "Nombre para usar la referencia"+ el TextBox que deseo que capte la informacion del formulario actual , esto poniendo las propiedades de modifiers de los objetos a utilzar en public

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo pero es que estoy indicando el formulario anterior es EntradadeMercancia por eso es el que referencio el codigo del CellContentDoubleClick esta en el formulario que se apertura al usuario no saber el RNC a utilizar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un concepto importante que hay que entender. Los formularios son objetos.

Esto quiere decir, que no importa que tengan algo visual, son objetos y se manejan con instancias como todos los otros objetos.

O sea...

Si tuvieras una clase animal, e hicieras lo siguiente:

```
private void funcion1()
{
   animal uno = new animal();
   ....
}

private void funcion2()
{
   animal uno = new animal();
   ....
}
```

Las dos variables uno, no representan el mismo animal. Representan animales (objetos) diferentes.

Y lo mismo pasa con los form. El problema es pensar que porque tiene un componente visual, el programa sabe que existe.

```
private void funcion1()
{
   form uno = new formloquesea();
   ....
}

private void funcion2()
{
   form uno = new formloquesea();
   ....
}
```

Las dos variables uno, no son el mismo formulario. Entonces, si queremos saber cual es el form que esta en uno, tenemos que guardar ese formulario en algun lado.

En tu caso, si ya levantaste el form Entradademercancia, es importante que entiendas que cuando en cualquier otra parte de tu codigo haces

```
Entradademercancia frm = new Entradademercancia();
```

Es **OTRO** formulario nuevo, por mas que se llame igual la variable y el formulario sea de la misma clase.

Lo que tenes que hacer, es cuando levantas el form de busqueda, pasarle una referencia a this, para que sepa quien es el formulario que lo llamo. y de esa forma, vas a poder devolverle cosas.

Comment: Gracias ya capte la idea.